# Using django-filter together with django-guardian

Tags: django, django-filter, django-guardian

I fail at making `django-filter` and `django-guardian` work together. What I need is an `ItemsFilterView` that lets the user list and filter all items that she has permission to view. Below are the parts of my code of which I think are most relevant. I can add more on request.

```
# filters.py
class ItemFilterSet(FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Item

# views.py
class ItemFilterView(FilterView):
    filterset_class = ItemFilterSet

# urls.py
url(r'^items/$', ItemFilterView.as_view(), name='item_list'),
```

I think `get_objects_for_user(request.user, 'view_item')` should be used to narrow the queryset to only the permitted items before `django-filter` gets its hands on them, but I do not find the right place to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the right location to add the logic:

```
# views.py
class ItemFilterView(FilterView):
    filterset_class = ItemFilterSet

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Item.objects.all()
        qs = get_objects_for_user(self.request.user, 'view_item', qs)
        return qs
```

Comment: I think it's not necessary to add the qs argument, it's the default behaviour.